# Limiting posts per day with Firebase? Querying all data too slow?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

I may be over thinking this, but I want to try and go with the best approach for this.

Basically I only want a specific number of posts to be posted per day.  I have the date as a `postedOn` key with the value being something like `02-09-2016`.

I am working on querying through the data to make sure that there are only a max of 15 posts per day.  Here is how i'm doing it:

```
  checkForLessThanFifteen: function(){
    var array = [];
    console.log('checkforless')
    var ref = new Firebase(rootUrl);
    var date = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    ref.child('items').once('value', function(snapshot){
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
        if(childSnapshot.val().postedOn === date)
        array.push(childSnapshot.val().songTitle);
      })
      console.log(array.length) //CODE RE ARRAY.LENGTH WILL GO HERE
    })
  }
```

Is this a suitable approach for this?  My concern is having to parse through all the data every time a post is attempted to be made.  With a lot of posts will this be too slow?  Any better methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nicfo's answer will work for for a day-by-day situation, but if you ever need multiple days it will be a bit difficult to get them into one flat array.

Instead you could do the following data structure:

```
{
  "messages": {
    "message_id": {
      "timestamp": 1454832000000
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can a Firebase query:

```
var ref = new Firebase('<>/messages');
var startAtDate = new Date(2016, 01, 07).getTime();
var endAtDate = new Date(2016,01, 08).getTime();
var query = ref.orderyByChild('timestamp').startAt(statAtDate).endAt(endAtDate);
query.on('child_added', function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.val()); // data from 02/07/2016
});
```

This will do a range query for messages on the date specified. As an added bonus here, if you ever need to do stretch out the date range you just change the `startAt` and `endAt` parameters.

Comment: Thanks! However I guess i'm lost on how the `startAt` and `endAt` methods work.  Doesn't that still need to query the whole database to get the timestamps from all entries?

Comment: Nope! You'll create a `indexOn` security rule that will allow the Firebase database to properly index your data for speedy queries :)

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that.  Do you have any link to documentation on this?  I'm still trying to wrap my head around it because I can't understand how it won't have to sort through all data...

Do I need to create a CRON job or something so that it indexes all of these properly?  Even if it indexes all posts, and then a new post is added to say, the bottom, how will Firebase know to index that without traversing through all of the data again to find that new last post?

Comment: Aha! Nevermind I get it now.  This is a huge help.  Thank you very much.  I will change my answer as this is definitely a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it now you read all the posts every time you read it.
To avoid this you could group them like this:

```
+ items
    + 02.09.2016
        + post1
        + post2
        + ...
        + post15
    + 02.09.2016
        + post1
        + post2
        + ...
        + post15
    + ...
```

then check if there are only 15 posts on that day like this:

```
var numberOfPosts = null;
var ref = new Firebase(rootUrl);
checkForLessThanFifteen = function(){
    var date = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('DD.MM.YYYY');
    ref.child('items').child(date).once('value', function(snapshot){
        numberOfPosts = snapshot.numChildren();
        console.log(numberOfPosts);
        return numberOfPosts;  // <- number of posts on that day.
    }

}
```